# How to get data from joined table with where clause in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join

i have an Entity with following mappings:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "template_product")
public class TemplateProductBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1821696115330320798L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Long productId;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to
    // Template
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "template_id")
    private TemplateBean template;
```

The Template Bean looks as following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "template")
public class TemplateBean implements Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 3752018564161042623L;

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name = "id")
     private Long id;

     @Column(name = "platform_id")
     private Long platformId;

     @Column(name = "template_name")
     private String templateName;

     // bi-directional many-to-one association to
     // TemplateProduct
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "template")
     private List<TemplateProductBean > templateProductBean;
```

The Problem im facing is, im very untrained when it comes down to use the JPA Interfaces.
 How can i use these to get the following query:

```
select template
            from Template template
            join TemplateProductBean templateProducts
            on template.templateId = templateProducts.template.templateId
            where templateProducts.productId in :templateProductIdList
```

How can i use the JPA Interfaces( javax.persistence.criteria.Root, javax.persistence.Join etc.) to build this query as a Predicate? I'm sorry if im being unclear, i have to use this and im not used to using the JPA. Thanks

Comment: Nobody? Please i really need help on this!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work

```
select t from TemplateBean t inner join t.templateProductBean tpb where tpb.productId in :templateProductIdList
```

More details on inner joins and HQL in general: [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-select)

Comment: Thanks but i meant how do i do this with the interfaces to build a Predicate? Like starting from an CriteriaQuery.from(TemplateProductBean.class) as query root and then add the joins and expressions via the interfaces to build a javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate representing the whole query?

Comment: Sorry, guess I didn't read carefully enough. As I also don't have any experience with these interfaces, I won't try to look smart anymore :/

Comment: Alright, i understand you ;) Thank you very much though!